# Request module: Is this the correct way to make consecutive POST requests with different body's?

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

So I am using the NodeJs "request" module to make multiple post requests, and I feel as though I may be doing it incorrectly. Is there a better way to approach this?

Lets say I have an array of different JSON bodies I need to send.

```
        var requests = [
                {
                    "Subject": "TestSubject1",
                    "Body": "TestBody1",
                    "PreferredLanguage": "en-US",
                    "Recipients": [
                        {
                            "FirstName": "TestName1",
                            "EmailAddress": "TestEmail1"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "Subject": "TestSubject2",
                    "Body": "TestBody2",
                    "PreferredLanguage": "en-US",
                    "Recipients": [
                        {
                            "FirstName": "TestName2",
                            "EmailAddress": "TestEmail2"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "Subject": "TestSubject3",
                    "Body": "TestBody3",
                    "PreferredLanguage": "en-US",
                    "Recipients": [
                        {
                            "FirstName": "TestName3",
                            "EmailAddress": "TestEmail3"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
```

Here is how I am attempting to do it.

```
         for(var i = 0; i < requests.length; i++){
                request.post(
                    {
                        url: 'https://testURL.com/messages',
                        json: requests[i],
                        method: 'POST'
                    },
                    function (e, r, body) {
                        console.log(body);
                    }
                )
            }
```

I have a feeling this is a very bad way of approaching this problem. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: You might want to save the requests into a json file. And then use npmjs.com/allrounder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All depends on your intentions:

You're fine if you need to **process requests' results separately**(all requests are asynchronous and will be handled by passed callback function separately).

But often you need to **make final action when all of our requests have completed**. You can use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) for this.

For example:

```
require("request/package.json"); // request is a peer dependency.
const requestPromiseAny = require("request-promise-any");

const requests = [
  {
    "name": "morpheus",
    "job": "leader"
  },
  {
    "name": "tom",
    "job": "leader"
  }
];
Promise.all(requests.map((requestJSON) => {
  return requestPromiseAny.post(
    {
      url: 'https://reqres.in/api/users',
      json: requestJSON,
      method: 'POST'
    });
})).then((responses) => {
  console.log(responses);
});
```

You can easily try it on [runkit](https://runkit.com/mogo69/example-of-promise-all-usage).

Comment: I like this, but it doesn't seem to be working. How can i print the body of each of the responses?

Comment: Sorry for incomplete answer. Are you using [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) for requests?
In order to use promises you need something like [request-promise-any](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise-any). I will update my example in original answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it that way. Generally speaking, you want to avoid making tons of HTTP calls, so if you have the ability to edit the API you are making the requests to, you could change the endpoint to take an array (your current `requests` array) and return whatever you need all in one HTTP request.

Comment: Ok thanks, but I do have another question. If I do it he above way, what do I do if I want to do something else after the final iteration of the loop? Does it exit automatically? Or is there some caviat, sync requests are asynchronous?

Comment: If you're talking about doing it the way you originally posted, you can do something after the final iteration of the loop by doing it outside the loop. If you want to do it ON the final iteration, you could do something like this inside of your callback (the `function(e, r, body) {...` part):   
    `if (i === requests.length - 1) {
      // Do your last iteration logic here
    }`
HTTP requests are always asynchronous, and the more you rely on, the more caveats you'll find. I'd highly recommend trying to find a way to do it in 1 HTTP call.

Answer (score 0):

You should not blindly make hundreds of parallel requests to a server.

You should have some limit on number of parallel request to a server other wise server might get down or server might block you as well

I personally use [eachLimit](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#eachLimit) function of node's `async` module in these type of situations.

Following is a working code

```
const async = require('async');
const request = require('request');
var limit = 2 //max 2 parallel request at time

var requests = [
    {
        "Subject": "TestSubject1",
        "Body": "TestBody1",
        "PreferredLanguage": "en-US",
        "Recipients": [
            {
                "FirstName": "TestName1",
                "EmailAddress": "TestEmail1"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Subject": "TestSubject2",
        "Body": "TestBody2",
        "PreferredLanguage": "en-US",
        "Recipients": [
            {
                "FirstName": "TestName2",
                "EmailAddress": "TestEmail2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Subject": "TestSubject3",
        "Body": "TestBody3",
        "PreferredLanguage": "en-US",
        "Recipients": [
            {
                "FirstName": "TestName3",
                "EmailAddress": "TestEmail3"
            }
        ]
    }
]

function iteratee(requestBody, cb) {
//this will be called for each item in the requests array
    console.log("request processing starts")
    request.post({
            url: 'https://testURL.com/messages',
            json: requestBody,
            method: 'POST'
        },
        function (e, r, body) {
            console.log(e);
            console.log(body);
            cb();
            console.log("request processing ends")
        });
}

function finalCallback(err) {
    //this will be called when all the requests are processed
}

async.eachLimit(requests, limit, iteratee, finalCallback)
```